# Versioning and caching static files: CSS, JS, images -- What to consider

Tags: caching, http-caching

For an (enterprise) web project i want to keep previous versions of the static files so that projects can decide for themselves when they are ready to implement design changes. My initial plan is to provide folders for static content like so:

```
company.com/static/1.0.0/
company.com/static/1.0.0/css/
company.com/static/1.0.0/js/
company.com/static/1.0.0/images/
company.com/static/2.0.0/
company.com/static/2.0.0/css/
company.com/static/2.0.0/js/
company.com/static/2.0.0/images/
```

Each file in these folders should then have a cache-policy to cache "forever" -- one year at least. I also plan to concatenate css files and js files into one, in order to minimize number of requests.

Then i would also provide a `current` folder (which symlinks to the latest released version)

```
company.com/static/current/
company.com/static/current/css/
company.com/static/current/js/
company.com/static/current/images/
```

This will solve my first problem (that projects and sub websites can lock their code to a certain version and can upgrade whenever they are ready).

But then I can see some caching issue. Now i cannot "just" cache `current` folder, since it will change for each release. What should my caching policies be on that folder.

Also, for each release, most of the static files will never change anyway. Is it relevant to cache them forever, and rename if there are changes?

I am looking for advice here, since i want to know about your best trade-off between caching and changing the files.

Answer (score 1):

Beware of HTTP caching. I looked into this some time ago.
[my blog article on the HTTP caching](http://www.adamish.com/blog/archives/255)

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand your point. You suggest no caching at all? I DO want caching so that the browser makes as few requests as possible. In order to DECREASE RESPONSE TIMES and thus increase user expierience.  Also i want to decrease bandwidth usage. So these are the boundaries within where i search for an answer. Given this, i cannot accept your answer.

Comment: If you use "current" symlinks and then update where the current symlink is pointing, browsers will still use the cached version for quite some time - possibly days in my experience. I'd recommend not using a current symlink approach. Keep it keyed on a meaningful version number in the path name - this way the caching will behave in the way you want.

Comment: OK so i should understand your answer in the context of not using a `current` symlink? Please add any other advice you may want to share!

Comment: @JesperRønn-Jensen Yes, I'd advise against the current symlink approach. Apologies this isn't a complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are three approaches you can select from:

1. Use resource's path as a cache key, i.e. when it changed - the browser will have to download new version of your resources. In this case you don't need `/current` folder at all, you just need to avoid `.html` page caching and put appropriate path to your resources in it.
2. You can point browser to `/current` folders only and add ETag to your resources, in this case another server request will be made from the client, but it will be conditional request (i.e. with `If-None-Match` header), so you can return 304 response (with no resource body) until your customer decide to migrate to another version. Another drawback of such solution (if you have several customers who use different versions) is that `/current` folder will contain only some single version of the design.
3. As you're going to concatenate resources into single files, you can specify resource version as part of url: `/current/js/combined.js?version=1.0.0.0` But this is not much different from first approach.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I wouldn't do 3 especially in a corporate environment as it will prevent proxy servers from caching the resources

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth your while looking at how Google, Microsoft etc. have implemented the caching policies for their jQuery CDNs

Your policy of caching forever is OK for the versioned URLs.

For the current URLs you're obviously going to need a shorter expiry time.

Couple of things to consider:

- How are the applications going to be able to test against /current/ i.e. if they use it how do you know a change isn't going to break an existing application?
- Caching forever is only really about reducing requests during the 'current session' as most browser caches aren't big enough to hold files for a long time (they get removed as people browse others sites)